# cannot import name 'PowerShellActivator' from 'virtualenv.activation.powershell' (unknown location)

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to establish a virtualenv for a django project,
so when I try this command on cmd or the powershell:

```
virtualenv my_env
```

this error show up:

```
cannot import name 'PowerShellActivator' from 'virtualenv.activation.powershell' (unknown location)
```

pip and the virtualenv package is up to date,
This is the first time happened to me, and before everything was working fine,
Also I searched on the web but I couldn't find something
can someone find out what is wrong about this ?

Comment: Check if this helps https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing another python version